# How to make scripts/programs that run in the background

Tags: background

So, I have a VDS and I was wondering how I could make a program or script that runs constantly in the backgroud. Something that can check sessions/cookies to make sure that htey are still good/valid. RUn queries through databases to make sure that people havent been idle too long, and if they have been then log them out. Stuff to that effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this while a visitor is there, you could just have a while loop that checks every 10 seconds with the server to see whether things are still valid

Client side, use JS
Server side, use any language you want

Comment: What im trying to do is serverside though. Because I will be using the server to supply a database to a few apps for Android

Comment: Right, so send `xmlHttpRequest()`s to the server using JavaScript, and serve the request using PHP, Python, whatever language you are using to manage the app.

Comment: I would prefer not to do it that way. I know there is a way to develop services and applications to run on the serverside, but I dont know how or where to begin, thats what im looking for